# Validation to restrict user form uploading heavy files

Tags: javascript, validation, file-upload, limit

Hi I am using this code to restrict user from uploading the heavy files above 5mb. But this is only working for first file filed not for the rest of file fileds.

```
var n=1;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.add_field').click(function(){

        if(n < 5)
        {
        n=n+1;
        var newid="file"+n;
        var input = $('#file1');
        var clone = input.clone(true);
        //clone.removeAttr ('id');
        clone.attr('title','file'+n);
        clone.attr('id','file'+n);
        clone.val('');
        clone.appendTo('.input_holder');}
    });
    $('.remove_field').click(function(){
                if(n!=1)
                {
                n=n-1;
                if($('.input_holder input:last-child').attr('id') != 'input_clone'){
                $('.input_holder input:last-child').remove();
                }
        }
    });

    $("#file1").change(function () 
    {   
        var iSize = ($("#file1")[0].files[0].size / 1024); 
        if(iSize>5000)
        {
            alert("Too Large FIle");
            example_reset_html('file1d');
        }
    }); 

    $("#file2").change(function () 
    {   
        var iSize = ($("#file2")[0].files[0].size / 1024); 
        if(iSize>5000)
        {
            alert("Too Large FIle");
            example_reset_html('file1d');
        }
    }); 



});

function example_reset_html(id) {
$('#'+id).html($('#'+id).html());
```

}

I checked this all browser and tried hacks but it seems that something is wrong and not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you bind your event on $('.input_holder')? It seems that element holds all file inputs so you only have to bind the change event to their parent.

```
$(".input_holder").change(function (e) 
    {   
        if(e.target.type==="file"){
          var iSize = (e.target.files[0].size / 1024);
          if(iSize>5000)
          {
              alert("Too Large FIle");
              example_reset_html(e.target.id);
          }
        }
});
```